# plog library saving same data twice

Tags: c++, logging, visual-c++

I am trying to use plog library to enable logging in my application. Whenever I log some data it gets stored twice in the file.

```
std::string errorFilePath = "error.log
plog::init(plog::error, errorFilePath.c_str(), 104857600, 3);
LOG_ERROR << "Hello World!";
```

> 2018-10-09 09:43:45.866 ERROR [9888] [main@10] Hello World!
>   2018-10-09 09:43:45.866 ERROR [9888] [main@10] Hello World!